# Find the dimension of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

$V$ is the vector space of all polynomials over $\mathbb R$. Let $U$ be the subspace of polynomials such that $2\leq \dim U \leq n$. Also fix points $a,b\in \mathbb R$, where $a\neq b$. let $W$ be the subspace of polynomials which vanish at both $a$ and $b$, that is $f(a)=0=f(b)$ for all $f\in W$. Find the dimension of the subspace $W\cap U$.

I have no idea how to start the question. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you know the rank of $f\mapsto (f(a), f(b))$?

Comment: So all polynomials in W will be of the form $(x-a)(x-b)Q(x)$ where Q is of the appropriate degree. So given the dimension of U, what does this tell us ?

Comment: are you sure that $U$ is just a subspace and not a subspace of say polynomials of degree $\le n$?

Comment: I have been given that $V$ is infinite dimensional

Comment: @user138017: If that comment goes to me, I asked for $U$. Because it could basically be anything from $\dim U - 2$ to $\dim U$.

Comment: @user251257 yes, the comment goes to you. I meant $U$ is just a subspace with dimension between 2 to $n$.

Comment: @user138017: Depending on $U$, $\dim(U\cap W)$ could be $\dim U$, $\dim U - 1$, and $\dim U - 2$.

Comment: @user251257 can I ask why $\dim (U\cap W)$ could be different dimensions?

Comment: @user138017: Oh sorry, my examples were wrong. Take the span of following sets $\{1, x\}$, $\{ 1, (x-a)(x-b) \}$, $\{ (x-a)(x-b), (x-a)(x-b)x \}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Let $U$ be subspace generated by $x^2+a^2$ and $x^4+b^2$ ($a\neq b$), so $dim(U)=2$ and $U\cap W=\{0\}$ i.e., $$dim(U\cap W)=0.$$

Let $U$ be subspace generated by $(x-a)(x-b)x^m$ for $2\leq m \leq i\leq n-1$, then $$dim(U)=dim(U\cap W)=i+1$$.